# Problem with loading JSON file in React Router

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, react-router

I try to get only the name's region in this API link but it shows me errors in the properties of the `setState`. Syntax problem or something else?

By the way: Why I use this case, map function? For future purposes.

Thanks!

App Js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Region from './region';
import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = "/" component={Region}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Region extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            items:[],
            isLoad:false
        }
    }

    ComponentDidMount () {
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/europe").then(res=>res.json()).then(JSON=> {
            this.setState ({
                isLoad = true,
                items = JSON,
            }) 
        })
    }

    render () {
        let {isLoad,items} = this.state;

        if(!isLoad) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        else {
            return <div>
                <ul>
                    {items.map(items=>(
                        <li key={items.name}> </li> 
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    }
}

export default Region;
```

json file: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/europe

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind `.map()` is you get an opportunity to manipulate your array elements by accessing each elements and returning a different way, structure. In React case it helps to render proper **JSX** elements for `render()` method. Suggested read [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from React's official documentation.

Read from [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

First issue is wrongly passed properties to `setState()`, please note that I'm using `:` instead of `=`. Try to change as the following:

```
this.setState({
   isLoad: true,
   items: JSON,
});
```

Additionally you can try the following - you had the same name for current element as the array itself - it just better to have different name:

```
return <div>
     <ul>
         {items && items.map(e => <li key={e.name}> {e.name} </li>)}
     </ul>
</div>
```

I hope that helps!